# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting the following error on my post method. I have a Laravel API and a Angular frontend.

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /Users/andre/Docume

Here is the create function.

```
public function store($userid, PropertyRequest $request) 
{
    $user = User::find($userid);
    $advert = $user->property()->create($request->all());
    return response()->json($advert);
}
```

Here is the route.

```
Route::prefix('advertisement')->group(function () {
    Route::post('{id}/store', 'API\PropertyController@store');
});
```

The userId is being passed to the route from the Angular application.

Any idea what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have right data (array with data) in your `$request->all()` call.

Comment: I have it as a form request. The correct data is in the fields. Its saying argument 1 is incorrect, but thats the id. It should not be an array

Comment: Try to replace `store($userid, PropertyRequest $request)` with `store(PropertyRequest $request, $userid)` or `store(Request $request, $userid)`. And also check that `$userid` is really `int` and `$request->all()` is really `array` (use `dd(...)`).